Cannot run Flutter app on Android emulator, no matter how hard I try, and keep getting more and more errors
I've been trying to make a Flutter app. I'm trying to integrate it with Firebase as well.
I was able to test it on Microsoft Edge fine, but... considering that I'm aiming for a mobile app.
I want to be able to test it using the emulator. But, no matter how many times I downloaded a new Gradle version, or changed the Java JDK I was using,
I've changed the environment variables regarding both JDK and Gradle, and reworded my code in my build.gradle, gradle-wrapper.properties, settings.gradle files, and tried to rebuild/sync over and over using flutter clean and flutter pub get, and so on. but then nothing's worked.
I've already tried looking up solutions on here, but it seems like everything I tried hasn't been working.
Whenever I try running my Flutter app in the emulator, I get errors like this:

Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered.
This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the
command-line tools that were released at different times.

However, I have updated my SDK tools in Android Studio countless times already. I even uninstalled and reinstalled both Android Studio and cmdline-tools multiple times and have updated the code in my files to reflect those changes.
The details I can give:

from running flutter doctor, Android SDK version is 34.0.0

Java JDK is JDK-17 (since I heard Android Studio includes JDK 17 as its bundled Java version, I figured this would work better for compatibility).

Gradle for my system is 8.0.1


build.gradle (app):
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" // Google services plugin
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" // Flutter plugin
}

android {
    namespace = "com.flutterapp.name"
    compileSdk = 34
    ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.flutterapp.name"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
}


flutter {
    source = "../.."
}


build.gradle (android):
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.10"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


Also, I have

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.1-all.zip

in gradle-wrapper.properties, and flutter doctor doesn't reveal any obvious errors either
What am I doing wrong here?

What Android Studio version are you using (if at all)?

I think you need to mention your Flutter Version, Your Android Studio version, The error response you received and if you can run a clean flutter app (The base flutter counter App created with flutter create)

Also, provide the messages it generates (i.e., warnings and error messages) every time you run your app.

I think you should consider flutter doctor -v command for more detailed output.

Have you already added the Firebase plugin to your app?

The Android studio version I'm using is the most recent one (so, ladybug 2024.2.1). @tomerpacific

Flutter version is Flutter 3.24.5 @aolsan

@DevQt_PH I've already added Firebase plugin (I actually tried to run a version without the Firebase stuff, and got the same problem).  The error message I was getting for the emulator I wrote in my question

Aside from a warning message from the log, is there an error message that prevents your app from running properly?

Don't forget to respond to the answer to your question to let the community understand what happened next with your case. Thank!

@DevQt: I wonder if I could ask you not to use Code Formatting for names of software in your post edits? Just use the usual rules for proper nouns, and observe unusual case rules for the software if that look better e.g. MySQL. No additional formatting is required for readability.

@halfer, Okay, and I agree. I apologize about that. Hehe. I'll consider that next time I edit a post.

@DevQt: thanks! These ones are already fixed.

According to the official documentation, one of the most important things to consider when creating an emulator on Android Studio is:

The API level of the target device is important, because your app
doesn't run on a system image with an API level that's lower than the
one required by your app, as specified in the minSdk attribute in the
app manifest file. For more information about the relationship between
system API level and minSdk, see Version your app.

Please read the create and manage virtual devices documentation if there is something you need to check first,
and I hope you set it up correctly
Now, on the issue of,

Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered.
This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the
command-line tools that were released at different times.

Have you tried this?
Go to Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools (Tab) > and update Android SDK Command-line Tools to latest.

Note that if any other SDK tools have a new version to update, update them too.
And to properly add firebase you have to only add firebase_core and then you need to consider to not use the version of >= 3.7.0 because,

update Android SDK to version 33.5.1

Since your Android SDK version is 34.0.0
So instead of manually adding the specific version of firebase_core plugin to pubspec.yaml, use the terminal to do so, flutter pub add firebase_core
Restart your Android Studio by manually closing and reopening it or if necesssary, perform File > Invalidate Caches....
If you still want to resolve the warning, just maintain the latest Android Command-line Tools and Android Studio versions.
Note: If the warning persists, you can ignore it for now without doing anything as long as your project runs as expected.
I hope it helps!

I had a similar error just yesterday. I updated my Android Studio and then got the same build/gradle errors you are getting. The problem seems to relate to Flutter trying to use the built-in Android Studio JDK version (which, as of version Ladybug, seems to be beyond the compatibility of Flutter). You should run:
flutter doctor --verbose
to get the full Flutter doctor output. Then confirm what Java version Flutter is using. You can find this under the
Android Toolchain section: Java version Java(TM) SE ... (build ?). 

If this is something other than 17 (as you described using), there is a discrepancy.
Now you just have to update the path Flutter uses for its JDK by running this command:
flutter config --jdk-dir=<PATH_TO_JDK_17_DIR>

Also try cleaning your project using flutter clean and then flutter pub get.
In my case, this solved the error. It took me way too long to figure out. Let me know if there are any more issues.

Yeah, I already tried that. When I ran flutter doctor --verbose, it outputted this: "Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.12+8-LTS-286)".   It did take me like at least a day to try to change it from jdk 23 to jdk 17 (I thought downgrading would help, thinking maybe it was so recent that it was causing issues with Flutter). But it's still printing that error when I try to run the app in the emulator
